# Is it possible to use the bagging technique with two different algorithms in scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is it possible to use a bagging technique with two different algorithms like Logistic Regression and Random Forest or (almost) any other algorithm?

I would need somethings that returns an averaged or anyway combined probability and prediction. It would be for a classification task.